# Prove x ⋅ e = x for all x ∈ G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite set and $\cdot$ a binary operation on $G$ such that:

- The operation $\cdot$ is associative;
- $\forall x, y, z \in G, (x \cdot y = x \cdot z) \implies y = z$ and $(y \cdot x = z \cdot x) \implies y = z$

  1. Show that there exists $e \in G$ such that for all $x \in G, e \cdot x = x$.
  2. Show that we also have $\forall x \in G, x \cdot e = x $. 
     (Hint: Show that there exists $e'$ such that $x \cdot e′ = x$ for all $x \in G$ and that $e′ = e$).

I already proved 1, but I don't know how to prove 2. Can't we just use the associative of  $\cdot$  to say $x \cdot e =  e \cdot x = x$?

Comment: Hint: compute $e\cdotp e'$.

Comment: "Can't we just use the associative of ⋅⋅ to say x⋅e=e⋅x=x?"  That's not associativity; That commutativity.  If you assumed commutivity in proving part 1, than, I'm afraid you did it wrong and will need to redo it.

Comment: How did you prove 1?

Comment: For fix a ∈ G, f: G to G, x to ax. Then I use G is a finite set so it is surjective such that f(e)=a=a⋅e=e⋅a. And it proved there exists e in G. All x  ∈ G, can write as a⋅y. Then I do e⋅x= e⋅(ay)= (e⋅a)⋅y=a⋅y=x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e$ the left neutral element: $ex=x \quad \forall x$

and $e'$ the right neutral element $xe'=x \quad \forall x$.

We have:

$ee'= e'$ because $e$ is left neutral

$ee'=e$ beacuse $e'$ is right neutral

so $e=e'$

Answer (score 0):

Break the proof of part two into two parts. First, use a method similar to the proof of part 1 to show that $e'$ exists. Second, use proof by contradiction; assume $e \neq e'$ and show that this leads to a contradiction.

Associativity doesn't apply here; that says that $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$. You're thinking of commutativity, which doesn't necessarily hold for every group.